# What came first, the egg or the chicken?

Tags: java, multithreading

The essence of the task is to determine the winner in their dispute, without using volatility variables, locks, synchronized blocks/methods, and so on, at the disposal of join, slip, and isAlive. In my next code, the result is sometimes right and sometimes wrong. And I understand why, because sometimes, even if the egg ends later than the chicken, it will end by the time it reaches the isAlive check. So is it possible at all to achieve 100% of the correct result using these tools?

```
public class EggOrChicken {
    static Thread eggThread = eggVoice();
    static Thread chickenThread = chickenVoice();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("the start of the dispute...");
        eggThread.start();
        chickenThread.start();
        chickenThread.join();
        
        if (eggThread.isAlive()) {
            eggThread.join();
            System.out.println("the first was egg!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("the first was chicken!");
        }
        System.out.println("end of dispute!");
    }
    
    public static Thread eggVoice() {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("egg!");
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static Thread chickenVoice() {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("chicken!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "the first" you mean the first to terminate ? So you mean "the last" ? `the result is sometimes right and sometimes wrong`, define what is right, what is wrong.

Comment: *"So is it possible at all to achieve 100% of the correct result using these tools?"* - No.  (And I don't actually see the point of trying.)

Comment: @PeterMmm the one who exclaimed last came first. so the first who terminate came later

Comment: @StephenC, i appreciate your perspective. This task was given to me by a university lecturer =)

Comment: Yea ... well ... I have no idea what your lecturer was trying to teach you by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it reliably without any means of synchronization. If it works, it does so by chance.

In your case, the following can happen:

- `eggVoice` reaches `System.out.println("egg!");` but `eggThread` doesn't finish.
- `chickenVoice()` reaches `System.out.println("chicken!");`
- `chichickenThread` finishes.
- `chickenThread.join();` returns
- `eggThread.isAlive()` returns `true` even though `System.out.println("egg!");` has been executed.

Threads might pause and continue at any point in time. I/O (e.g. `System.out.println`) and sleeping makes this more likely but it could also happen between two CPU instructions.

At the end, you need to relax your constraints (e.g. by allowing `synchronized`).

Note that you might be able to write it in a way so that it always works while testing but it could break on other devices.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I asked a question to clarify whether it is possible to perform such a task by the means described and got an answer. Thank you!